# Generation of random phase factors

Tags: matlab

How to generate a random phase vector of size 1xN following these conditions:

```
N = [4,8,16,32]; % number of columns in output phase matrix (P_out)
theta= 1xN random values of theta
P=exp(j*theta)  % Phase factor
P_out= 1xN output row vector for different N values of theeta
```

Conditions for choosing theta:

1. `0 <= theta<= 2*pi      % Range of theta`
2. Each theta is any whole number multiple of smallest non-zero theta

   for e.g., say for `N = 4`:  `theta=[45,0,180,225]`% random angles

   here each value of theta is a multiple of 45: [45x0=45, 45x1=45, 45x4=180, 45x5=225]

Any help is much appreciated,
regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
N = 8;                                      % number of angles
A0 = randi(360);                            % random minimum angle in deg
A1 = N*A0;                                  % maximum angle
theta = linspace(A0,A1,N);                  % equidistant angles
theta = theta( randperm( numel(theta) ) );  % shuffle array
P = exp(1i.*theta*pi/180);                  % calculate phase factor
```

or directy in radians:

```
A0 = 0.2*pi;
A1 = N*A0;
...
P = exp(1i.*theta);
```

If you want sets of `P` for different values of `N` you need to store the arrays in a cell array (or struct) as every array `P` has a different length.

You can use `cellfun` to achieve that.

```
function P_out = getPhaseFactorSet()

N = {4,8,16,32};                             % number of angles
P_out = cellfun(@getPhaseFactor,N)

end

function P = getPhaseFactor( N )
A0 = randi(360);                             % random minimum angle in deg
A1 = N*A0;                                   % maximum angle
theta = linspace(A0,A1,N);                   % equidistant angles
theta = theta( randperm( numel(theta) ) );   % shuffle array
P{1} = exp(1i.*theta*pi/180);                % calculate phase factor
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but my requirement is random angles(1xN) and each is a whole number multiple (because theta can be zero also but not necessary always) of smallest non-zero angle.In your code value of theta would be same every time.

Comment: @that was not clear from your question, have a look at the edit

Comment: Sorry to bother you but with your code i have to set the minimum and maximum angle.Couldn't this be a random process to get angles randomly from 0 to 360 degrees.

Comment: Initially it's not random, because you need equidistant angles, right? It gets random in this line: `theta = theta( randperm( numel(theta) ) );``- which shuffles the angles. For example for `A0 = 15` and `A1 = 360` it could return: `75    30    90    60   120   105    15    45`

Comment: Or do you want to have a random starting value? I tought you just want  a random order.

Comment: Sorry for not framing a right question.Yes a random starting value will solve that.Thank you.

Comment: That works :) but could i get all different values of theta which are some whole number multiples of smallest theta.I do not need fractional theta.

Comment: It would help enormously if you would state everything like that, from the beginning... Have a look at the last edit.

Comment: +1 for your patience: I will keep in mind next time to make things clear before posting.I posted it in haste.