# distribute phases uniformly in range of -pi to pi

Tags: matlab, random

let us consider following article and equation 1

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.30.5925&rep=rep1&type=pdf

what i want is to generate  phases uniformly in [-pi pi]interval,let say i need to generate four  uniformly distributed phases in this range,i have tried following result

```
y=zeros(1,4);
for i=1:4
y(i)=-pi+(pi-(-pi)+1)*rand;
end
```

which gave me following result

```
2.79219092856020    3.45545787388109    -2.21672413895542   3.51069296177449
```

but it seems in correct result,so when i have made mistake?please help me

Comment: `2*pi*(rand(1,4)-0.5)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generation of random phase factors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451482/generation-of-random-phase-factors)

Comment: thanks for this link,i was not able to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you have added 1 to the interval here:

```
y(i)=-pi+(pi-(-pi)+1)*rand;
                  ^^^
                why +1 here ???
```

This should just be:

```
y(i)=-pi+(pi-(-pi))*rand;
```

Comment: :D ,because in some range random number generator use   +1,for example in c++

Comment: I think you are getting confused between generating random *integers* and random real numbers.